# IET Software journal latex template

Tags: templates

Does anyone have the IET Software journal latex template ?
I was looking for it for the past two weeks but in vain. The journal does not provide a latex template.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx! The usual rule if the journal provides no further guidance but does accept LaTeX is to use the `article` class and only an _absolute_ minimum of packages to get your text to work. (If the journal want print-like layout they'll provide a template or class.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the ITE [Research Journals FAQs](http://www.theiet.org/resources/journals/research/):

> **Is there a LaTeX template I can use?**
>
> Unfortunately **we do not have a
>   template for LaTeX.** Please refer to our author guide.
>
> **What are acceptable source files?**
>
> Main document - doc. pdf (**tex.** files
>   must be supplied with the pdf)

Effectively, in the [`Home > Journals & magazines > Author guide - IET research journals`](http://digital-library.theiet.org/journals/author-guide) one can read:

> 2.3.1. Revised papers should be submitted in their source file format (.doc, docx or .tex files for text and .eps, jpeg or .tif files for
>   figures). **If your paper has been prepared using LaTeX, please also
>   upload a single .pdf file of the paper together with the LaTeX source
>   file and the figures**.

Also relevant:

> 5.2.  Format: papers must be typed ... **Authors should not copy the format of the published journal. All accepted papers will be edited
>   into the IET Research Journals house-style.** Please double space and 
>   ....

Therefore, it seem that the  LaTeX template is mostly irrelevant. Probably is a good idea use only some  essential packages as `graphicx`, and stand in the standard `article` class following the format requirements of this point.

The exception in  *theiet.org* seem to be the [Author guide for Electronics Letters](http://digital-library.theiet.org/journals/el/author-guide) where you can download a LaTeX document class (`el-author.cls`) and a example-template. (`sample.tex`).

Answer (score 4):

IET has recently published a LaTeX template for its journal submission. See their [author guide](http://digital-library.theiet.org/journals/author-guide#presentation) for more information or use the [direct link to the .zip archive](http://digital-library.theiet.org/files/IET_ResearchJournals_latex.zip).

Comment: Hello and welcome to TeX.sx! I've added a link to the author's guide to your answer to make it stand on its own.

Comment: @wrtlprnft The links was already part of Usman Ilyas' answer.

Answer (score 1):

IET's LaTeX template is downloadable here:

http://digital-library.theiet.org/files/IET_ResearchJournals_latex.zip